# What will be the best tool to automate a Single Page Application test cases

Tags: selenium, testing, automation, webdriver, protractor

I have a new website to test which is a Single page application (SPA) and I'm not sure which tool shall I use to automate it. I thought of Selenium and Protractor but Protractor would not be a good idea as my site has nothing to do with AngularJS and in that case is it like Selenium WebDriver is the only option or there are any other tool available in market?
If selenium is the only good option then what sort of challenge I can face?

Comment: Yes, you can user selenium webdriver java with testng framework.

Comment: Thanks guys for your valuable responses.. so I'll go with WebDriver only using POM framework.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for Watir-Webdriver and Ruby! Main benefits - easy to read and understand code, ruby flexibility, power and irb debugger, speed and reliability. As for challenges - one would be of integrating technologies (if your site uses C# as the backend - i would definitely go with C# and Selenium-Webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can go with selenium webdriver with a framework like POM(Page object Model).

Page object model gives flexibility and maintainability for you scripts.

Refer:-

http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/page-object-model/

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

In case of one page application its will be bad idea to use selenium.

add all the dll's to your project, run the webDriver in your code and so on ...

The best idea will be using (.Net webBrowser + MSHtml) [in case that your test will be on internet explorer web browser]

**The Benefits:**

- Speed !
- Build in Framework.